# Get the days remaining from a methods rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have a starts_at attribute that is a standard `DateTime` data type. I want to take that time and the current Time to come up with `3` days remaining until event. This is my current method

```
def days_remaining
  (Date.parse(starts_at) - Date.current).to_i
end
```

but this is giving me this error `no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String`

This seems pretty straight forward but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date.parse` is expecting `String` argument, but `starts_at` is `DateTime`.
`to_date` method will convert datetime to date.

```
def days_remaining
  (starts_at.to_date - Date.current).to_i
end
```

Though, I don't think this is 100% correct way to find remaining days.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) method that can be used for this kind of thing. There's also the [dotiw](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) gem that offers more customisation of the output:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, 2.weeks.from_now, only: :days)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def days_remaining
  (starts_at.to_date...Date.current).to_a.count
end
```

This might be what you need. Creates a range of dates, convert to array, each entry is a day, then count those